# CSS Trouble making text expand and stay centered with circular expanding div

Tags: css

I'm a 3-day beginner enjoying every minute of CSS and everything web development related.

I'm trying to make the text inside the div expand along with it on hover.
Not sure as to how to keep the text centered and make it expand when the div expands.

Thank you in advance.

Here's the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/28dozgcw/

> 

```css
.circle+.container {
  height: 15em;
  width: 15em;
  background-color: skyblue;
  background-size: 200%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  border: 1rem transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 35%;
  margin: 0% 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.circle+.container:hover {
  opacity: 100%;
  height: 25em;
  width: 25em;
  transition: 1s;
}

h1 {
  position: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h1> Lorem Ipsum </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `<h1>` `.circle` and give it the following:

```
display: flex;
flex-flow: column nowrap;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

If you want the `<h1>` to scale proportionally with the `.circle` add the following:

```
.circle:hover h1 {
  font-size: 3.2rem;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

Note: I used `rem` instead of `em`. `rem` is relation to the root `font-size` (`html {font: 1ch...}`), `em` is in relation to the `font-size` of parent element. If you want everything to scale proportionally, just change the root `font-size`.

```css
html {
  font: 1ch/1 'Segou UI'
}

.circle {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 15rem;
  width: 15rem;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.4;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.circle:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
  height: 25rem;
  width: 25rem;
  transition: 1s;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
}

.circle:hover h1 {
  font-size: 3.2rem;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<header class="circle">
  <h1>Centered Title</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text isn't even centered when the element is *not*  hovered.  To center it in both situations, add `justify-content: center;` to the flex container:

```css
.circle + .container {
  height: 15em;
  width: 15em;
  background-color: skyblue;
  background-size: 200%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  border: 1rem transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 35%;
  margin: 0% 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.circle+.container:hover {
  opacity: 100%;
  height: 25em;
  width: 25em;
  transition: 1s;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h1> Lorem Ipsum </h1>
</div>
```